# Why is my nth-child css selector not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have four of the same element I want to style differently. My HTML is as follows and the class I want to use is the clientcontainer class.

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="client">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="#" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="client">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="#" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="client">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="#" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="client">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="#" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I added the following CSS

```
.clientcontainer:nth-child(1) {margin-top:0px; };
.clientcontainer:nth-child(2) {margin-top:100px; };
.clientcontainer:nth-child(3) {margin-top:300px; };
.clientcontainer:nth-child(4) {margin-top:200px; };
```

However, when I run it, I only find the first clientcontainer class is styled while it doesn't work on the other classes. I tried adding the wpb_wrapper class before each of these elements but that didn't seem to work either. Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: remove the `;` you have. It's invalid inside CSS

Comment: Ah that was probably it! I went back to this CSS and I was confused why it suddenly started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class counts *siblings*. You're not counting siblings. You're counting *cousins*, because each element you're targeting is the child of parent siblings.

Try this instead:

```
.wpb_wrapper:nth-child(1) > .clientcontainer {margin-top:0px; }
.wpb_wrapper:nth-child(2) > .clientcontainer {margin-top:100px; }
.wpb_wrapper:nth-child(3) > .clientcontainer {margin-top:300px; }
.wpb_wrapper:nth-child(4) > .clientcontainer {margin-top:200px; }
```

UPDATE: Question revised. HTML altered. Here's the solution now:

```css
.clientcontainer:nth-child(1) { height: 20px; background: orange; }
.clientcontainer:nth-child(2) { height: 20px; background: lightgreen; }
.clientcontainer:nth-child(3) { height: 20px; background: aqua; }
.clientcontainer:nth-child(4) { height: 20px; background: pink; }
```

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="client">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="client">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="client">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3 clientcontainer">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="client">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that but now all four client containers are following the first rule. Wouldn't I need four wpb_wrapper classes for this to work?

Comment: Sorry I have realised now that I didn't put in my HTML correctly. I have now updated it. There is now one wpb_wrapper element that contains the four clientcontainer classes.

Comment: Well, now that you've altered the HTML, your original CSS code should work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/73frxjh1/1/

Comment: Yes I realised that I had left an errant ; in my original CSS. Once I removed it, it then started working.

Answer (score 1):

Every element that is a member of the `clientcontainer` class is the **first** child of its parent element.

The selector is nth **child**, not nth in document.

You could target based on the position of the `wpb_wrapper` element with a descendant combinator.